# How to change button text and locations in mac pkg installer page

Tags: macos, installation, pkgbuild, productbuild

I have built my pkg in mac using pkgbuild and productbuild. How can we change the text and position of UI buttons in installer pages[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can't**. The UI comes from Apple's "Installer.app" and the position of UI elements can not be changed.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is their any way we can skip any of these steps or can i merge them in to one screen

Comment: Not sure. But if you are looking for customizations, please look at the xml attributes available in distribution.dist of a package. You may get some explanation at http://macinstallers.blogspot.in/2013/01/xml-attributes-of-packagemaker.html